# CKEditor5 Online Builder Failed to Render - React Version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ckeditor

I was trying to use the CKEditor5's [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/react.html#using-the-ckeditor-5-online-builder) to render the editor in my React 18 app but after I put my code in, the editor did not render and in the console, I saw the following error.

```
ckeditor.tsx:156  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
    at to._createEditor (ckeditor.tsx:169:1)
    at Vr._creator (ckeditor.tsx:133:1)
    at editorwatchdog.js:115:1
    at async to._initializeEditor (ckeditor.tsx:151:1)
    at async to.componentDidMount (ckeditor.tsx:102:1)
```

I followed the instruction to put the downloaded CKEditor5 folder in the root directory of my project. The following is my code to integrate the editor into the React component,

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react'
import { Editor } from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';


const DashboardPage = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-body'>

          {/* begin::Editor */}
          <div className='mx-auto'>
            <CKEditor
              editor={Editor}
              data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
              onReady={editor => {
                // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
              }}
              onChange={(event, editor) => {
                // const data = editor.getData();
                // console.log({ event, editor, data });
              }}
              onBlur={(event, editor) => {
                console.log('Blur.', editor);
              }}
              onFocus={(event, editor) => {
                console.log('Focus.', editor);
              }
              }
            />
            {/* end::Editor */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

These are the versions of the CKEditor5 used,

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-balloon": "^38.0.1",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react": "^6.0.0",
"ckeditor5-custom-build": "file:./ckeditor5",
```

The thing is that I tried the prebuilt `classic`, `balloon` versions of CKEditor5 they all render nicely in the page. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you create an reproducible example using https://codesandbox.io/?

Comment: Why the lines inside of `onChange` is commented? As it is actually for execution.

Comment: forgot to uncomment them, was testing which line is causing the error but it's not that block of code causing the errors

Answer (score 1):

I tried to research this [CKEditor 5 online builder](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/integrations/react.html#using-the-ckeditor-5-online-builder). As they mentioned in their docs:

> If you want to use the CKEditor 5 online builder, make sure that the watchdog feature is not selected. The React integration comes with the watchdog feature already integrated into the core.

You could try the below snippet:

```
<CKEditor
        editor={Editor}
        data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
        watchdogConfig={ { crashNumberLimit: 10 } } //try to add this `watchdogConfig` feature
...
/>
```

For more reference, this is a [sample example](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-react/blob/master/demo-react-18/src/EditorDemo.tsx).

Hope this helps!

Comment: not sure what happened, I think there was corrupted in the cache causing the error, somehow it worked without setting the `watchdogConfig` so horray! thanks for the answer tho! :)

Answer (score 0):

Anyway I realised the real issue causing the problem - I `yarn` installed multiple prebuilt editors e.g., `BalloonEditor` and `ClassicEditor` along with my online built editor and somehow they cannot exist together hence causing the error.

Putting this out there for others' reference :)